# Executing a jQuery script when rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'd like to execute a jQuery script while rendering an action in my rails controller.

To be more precise, I have this function in my users controller ...

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # Successful save
    else
      render action: "new", layout: "signup"
    end
end
```

... and I want to add a class to a specific element in my `new.html.erb` file. I need to do that when rendering only because I don't want the class to be added **beforehand**.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705333/rails-trigger-javascript-events-from-controllers Something like this?

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. You want an HTML element to have (or not have) a class based on some condition? Executing a JQuery script when rendering does not strike me as the way to go about such a thing.

Comment: Well in the context of Rails, I don't know If I can call this a condition. I'd like my element to have (or not have) a class depending on the action rendering this particular element.

Comment: in your `new.html.erb` file, you can access the `params[:action]` which will tell you if you submitted the form and the user failed to save (if you are rendering `new` under the `params[:action]` create, it means something went wrong). **Option 2**: setting `@some_variable` in the create action and test it in the view. **Option 3** check for `@user.errors`, if there are errors in the `@user` object then it means the save was not successful. In conclusion, **there is no need to use jQuery** for that, you have to use a way to differentiate the `new` action from the (failed) `create` action.